# Implementing a (javascript) plugin in R Leaflet

Tags: javascript, java, r, plugins, leaflet

I am building a Leaflet application in R.

I want to use this plugin https://github.com/Turbo87/leaflet-sidebar
However, I have no clue where to start.

Guides on implementing Javascript Leaflet plugins in R have not been able to help. Does anyone have any steps/guidance/code I can follow to implement the plugin in my R Leaflet?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is where I'm currently at:

```
sidebarPlugin <- htmlDependency("leaflet-sidebar", "0.2.0",
                            src = c(href = "https://github.com/Turbo87/leaflet-sidebar.git"),
                            script = "src/L.Control.Sidebar.js")

registerPlugin <- function(map, plugin) {
  map$dependencies <- c(map$dependencies, list(plugin))
  map}

testLeaflet <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles %>%
  addPolylines(data = dijkjson)%>%
  #register plugin on this map instance
  registerPlugin(sidebarPlugin)%>%
  addControl("Test2", position = "topright")%>%
  # Add your custom JS logic here. The `this` keyword
  # refers to the Leaflet (JS) map object.
  onRender("function(el, x) {
       var sidebar = L.control.sidebar('sidebar', {
       position: 'left'}).addTo(this);
       map.addControl(sidebar).addTo(this);
       sidebar.show().addTo(this);
       }")
```

Comment: I don't think you are dumb but you should file an issue instead of complaining about insufficient documentation by the authors. I don't know the answer or I would point you to it.

Comment: Good idea, I filed an issue on the Github repository. Decided to remove the complaining part from my question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you still have not solved your problem.
A first step is to make sure that your htmlDependency source actually exists. 
With your path, I get the following response: 
{"error":"Not Found"}

[jsdelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/) provides most js libraries available through npm and github in application/javascript format. Using that instead of the raw github path you could try:

```
sidebarPlugin <- htmltools::htmlDependency("L.Control.Sidebar", "0.2.1",
                            src = c(href = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Turbo87/leaflet-sidebar@0.2.1/src'), 
                            script = 'L.Control.Sidebar.js', stylesheet = 'L.Control.Sidebar.css')
```